# Wpf : Initialize class with parameters in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've a problem with my WPF application.

I've this class with this constructor:

```
public partial class FenetreMenu : UserControl
{
    public FenetreMenu(CDataJoueurs donneesBase)
    {
        Données = donneesBase;
        InitializeComponent();
        Initialisation();
    }
//...
```

And in my xaml code, I've tried to do this:

```
<local:FenetreMenu x:Name="FenetreMenu" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="700" 
   VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1119" Visibility="Hidden"/>
```

But it doesn't work, I cannot put a class who have a parameter in its constructor.

How can I resolve my problem ?

Comment: What is the same topic ? I've search and I've not found where...

Answer (score 0):

Put the arg in a property instead:

```
public partial class FenetreMenu : UserControl
{
    public FenetreMenu()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Initialisation();
    }

    public CDataJoueurs Données { get; set; }
//...
```

and then

```
<local:FenetreMenu x:Name="FenetreMenu" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
  Height="700" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1119" Visibility="Hidden" Données="..." />
```

The argument can be a static instance for instance:

```
{x:Static CDataJoueurs.Instance}
```

Comment: I've already do it but I don't want to create a new instance of the classe because the class CDataJoueurs share his properties with others UserControl so I'm obliged to put the (CDataJoueurs Données) on the constructor of the class FenetreMenu.
Do you have an other way please ? :)

Comment: Are you saying that you have a single instance of CDataJoueurs that you want to use in all instances of your UserControl? In that case you can provide that instance as a static argument. You'd have to create one instance and the put it in a new public static property somewhere.

Comment: No I have just one instance and I want to use it in 2 UserControl.

Comment: Ok, in that case you can "inject" the one instance using a static property as I showed above.